# Error while digitally signing a PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I am using following program for signing PDF (I got the complete sample from http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-2.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.DigestAlgorithms;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.CryptoStandard;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature;

public class C2_01_SignHelloWorld {

public static final String KEYSTORE = "src/main/resources/ks";
public static final char[] PASSWORD = "password".toCharArray();
public static final String SRC      = "src/main/resources/CA_Commercial_Construction.pdf";
public static final String DEST     = "results/chapter2/CA_Commercial_Construction_signed%s.pdf";

public void sign(String src, String dest, Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider, CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating the reader and the stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setReason(reason);
    appearance.setLocation(location);
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
    // Creating the signature
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE), PASSWORD);
    String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, PASSWORD);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    C2_01_SignHelloWorld app = new C2_01_SignHelloWorld();
    app.sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, 1), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS, "Signed for Testing", "Universe");
    app.sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, 2), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA512, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test 2", "Universe");
    app.sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, 3), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test 3", "Universe");
    //app.sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, 4), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.RIPEMD160, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test 4", "Ghent");
}}
```

I set up my own keystore using keytool but when I open the PDF and marked the certificate as trusted, I still get error - '**document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed**'. I dont really know what is going on here.

EDIT: There is no error in the program. The problem I face can be seen from this PDF link which I generated from above program: http://pasteboard.co/9hJX1Hv.png

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: @Jens, done. Here is the link - http://pasteboard.co/9hJX1Hv.png. Also read my EDIT

Comment: Please share a sample PDF created with your code and key for analysis.

Comment: Just to be sure I tried to reproduce the issue with a test PDF and keystore of my own. The output PDFs were accepted by Adobe, no "altered or corrupted" error. Thus, the issue is not due to iText or the code above but instead some external factor like the OP's test PDF or keystore, or the runtime environment (I used Java 8 with the unlimited JCE policy installed)...

Answer (score 0):

I changed DigestAlgorithm to SHA1 and 'document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed' error is gone. Pasting complete correct below:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.DigestAlgorithms;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.CryptoStandard;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature;

public class C2_01_SignHelloWorld {

public static final String KEYSTORE = "src/main/resources/ks";
public static final char[] PASSWORD = "password".toCharArray();
public static final String SRC      = "src/main/resources/CA_Commercial_Construction.pdf";
public static final String DEST     = "results/chapter2/CA_Commercial_Construction_signed%s.pdf";

public void sign(String src, String dest, Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider, CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating the reader and the stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setReason(reason);
    appearance.setLocation(location);
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
    // Creating the signature
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE), PASSWORD);
    String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, PASSWORD);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    C2_01_SignHelloWorld app = new C2_01_SignHelloWorld();
    app.sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, 1), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CADES, "Signed for Testing", "Universe");   // only change done was in this line to resolve this problem

}}
```

Comment: In this decade you surely don't want to write new software using SHA1 for signing, do you?

Comment: what is the alternative I have? Is it safe to conclude current iText (5.5.9) has a bug with SHA256?

Comment: *Is it safe to conclude current iText (5.5.9) has a bug with SHA256* - No. That is why I asked you (in a comment to your question) for a sample PDF with that error for analysis. The issue might also be due to the nature of your keystore or of your source document.

Comment: As just mentioned in a comment to you question, I could not reproduce your issue. So it is highly unlikely that *iText (5.5.9) has a bug with SHA256*.

Comment: JackSparrow as @mkl said probably the problem comes from the key... We had an smartcard which comes with a driver version for windows CSP access which produces a similar error on adobe (signing with iText or with adobe itself). With the new driver version we can sign a PDF using sha2 without errors.